# TControlList ScrollBar Disabled when Creating Form inside another Form

Tags: delphi

I'm creating a new screen in Delphi 10.4.2 and decided to use TControlList to list products. The problem I came across is that when creating the screen section inside a panel of the main screen (i divided each section into distinct units), even though TControlList lists the records normally, it is not creating the side scrollbar to view all the records. Would anyone know how to solve this? I've already tested using examples, the properties are the same and the problem persists.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3smhX.png)

Comment: You need to add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your q.

Answer (score 2):

Solved, in case anyone has this same problem, the component does not create a ScrollBar if it has less than 10 records in the ItemCount property, so it's just a matter of validating it for if you have less than 10 records in the database, put the default value of 10.